# search and replace issue with sed

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I need to simply search for numbers (say 1 to 100 in a txt file) and replace them with particular ID. Using the following command line;

```
sed -e 's/1/ID_one/g' -e 's/2/ID_two/g' -e 's/3/ID_three/g' ... infile > outfile
```

It does work for the first 9 numbers but then it starts to repeat for those numbers having similar digits like 10,11,12, ... which have 1 in them, or 20, 21, 22, ... which have 2 in them.

I think there should be a trick somewhere in the command line to avoid repeating!!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Put the bigger ones first? (assuming it processes them in order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word boundary:

```
$ echo '2 22' | sed 's/\b22\b/Change this/'
2 Change this
```

Comment: Great! It worked very well. Thank you for help. I put $ echo '1 100' | in front and done!